# Adding two lists to separate columns in csv file in Python

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv

I have two lists as below.

```
a=[1,3,5,6,7,12]
b=[23,45,67,67]
```

I need to have the lists in separate columns in csv file like this:

```
Item,Quantity 
[1,3,5,6,15],[23,45,67,67]
```

I tried using below code snippets, but I am not getting the result I want.

```
with open('sample_dataset.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-16', newline='') as outfile:
    rowlists = zip(a, b)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in rowlists:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The result is:

```
1,23
3,45
5,67
6,67
```

Using pandas

```
d=[a,b]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
my_df.to_csv('sample_dataset.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

The result is in different rows:

```
1,3,5,6,7.0,12.0
23,45,67,67,,
```

Your help and inputs are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your output example is not valid csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using csv Module.

**Ex:**

```
a=[1,3,5,6,7,12]
b=[23,45,67,67]

import csv
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow(["Item", "Quantity"])
    writer.writerow([a, b])
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much. How can I avoid blank rows in between?

Comment: @Rakesh they only had 6 rep.  How do you expect them to upvote unless you upvote their question?

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,3,5,6,7,12]
b=[23,45,67,67]

with open('sample_dataset.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Item,Quantity\n")
    f.write("{},{}\n".format(a, b))
```

Output file:

```
'''
Item,Quantity
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 12],[23, 45, 67, 67]

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(f'Item,Quantity\n[{",".join(map(str, a))}],[{",".join(map(str, b))}]')

Item,Quantity
[1,3,5,6,7,12],[23,45,67,67]
```